# How can I add an interactive sorting on expression column in Sql Server Reporting Services Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2012

Hi I am new to SSRS and I created a form. I also added a couple of column based on expressions. I was trying to sort the table on the basis of an expression column but the option is not available in cell properties - interactive sorting. Can anyone please guide me on how to achieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of solving this that I can think of.  You can either:

***Move your calculated columns to your Dataset***

When you add a dataset to a report, on the **Fields** tab you have the option to add Calculated Fields.  If you add your expression column here, you will be able to use it in the **Sort** tab of your Tablix just as you would a normal column.

[image: SSRS Dataset Calculated Field]

OR

***Repeat the expression in the Sort property.***

If you are not able to create your calculated field on your dataset (perhaps if you reference other datasets or do something out of scope), then you will need to duplicate your expression in the **Sort** tab of your Tablix.  *(To access this, click anywhere on your table and then right-click on the small grey square in the top left-hand corner of your table).*

[image: SSRS Tablix Sort expression]

If you click **Add** for a new Sort condition and hit the ***fx*** button, you can paste the same expression you used for your column into here and use it to sort your dataset.

The downside of this is that you're replicating your logic and potentially duplicating work.

Comment: Thanks. Can I do the first process after the report is created?

Comment: I deleted the column and re-entered using the first method. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you've got this sorted, but yes, you can add a Calculated Field to a Dataset at any time, either through SQL Server Data Tools or Report Builder.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the interactive shorting in a table you need to have a row group. So by this you can sort the whole table or only a portion of the table.

Say in your case you need to sort the table basis of some expression. For an example you need have an interactive sort based on the values. In the below screenshot I have 2 groups i.e. Customer and Project and I want to have an interactive sort based on the revenue.

[image]

Now right click on the Revenue and go to the 'Textbox' properties and select the group and sort by. Here in the screenshot I will sorting based on the total revenue for different Customers.

[image]

Now after running the report if you click on the `Revenue` column it will sort accordingly.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.